# How can I add a custom 'weight' field to a Linux process in task_struct and ensure inheritance during forking?

Tags: linux, process, fork

As part of my Operating Systems course homework (currently working on linux 18.04), I was given the task to add a few system calls to the linux kernel. This includes adding a field called 'weight' to the process control block, and the new syscalls will modify, or use this new weight field (it doesn't have a real use or purpose).

Currently I added the field 'weight' with value 0 in INIT_TASK in /include/linux/init_task.h:

```
#define INIT_TASK(tsk)  \
{                                   \
    INIT_TASK_TI(tsk)                       \
    .state      = 0,                        \
    .stack      = init_stack,                   \
    .weight = 0,                 \
     ...
```

and added the same field in task_struct in /include/linux/sched.h:

```
struct task_struct {
    #ifdef CONFIG_THREAD_INFO_IN_TASK
    /*
     * For reasons of header soup (see current_thread_info()), 
     * this must be the first element of task_struct.
     */
    struct thread_info      thread_info;
    #endif
    /* -1 unrunnable, 0 runnable, >0 stopped: */
    volatile long           state;
    long weight;
    ...
```

I'm trying to make any process inherit the 'weight' field from it's parent, meaning that the first process that was forked from the init process gets 'weight' = 0, and so on.
My question is how forking works with new fields. Should I modify the fork syscall to manually copy the new field, or does it manually take any variable from the init_task and copies it to the task_struct?

Comment: You'll need to include the minimum amount of your code (`c`, `python`, other?) that demonstrates your problem. Also include a tag for the programming language you are using. Be sure to use the `{}` tool from the Edit menu on mouse selected text to give correct formatting for `code/data/output/errMsgs/etc`. Good luck.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So my assumption was correct. When the init process forks, it copies every element from it's init_struct to the forked process' task_struct including any new field I added, so there is no need to modify the forking process.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).